# How do I get this file to be read as a variable?

Tags: python, path, command

Using *python 3.6.1*

Encountered an error stating:

> No such file or directory.

```
x = open(r'c:/Users/name/Desktop/CommercialArticles.txt/3_Biotech/3_Biotech\#1.txt', 'r');
```

This is the path given when I drop the file in terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your file path is totally wrong. In windows press `SHIFT` and then `Right Mouse Click` on file will show you context menu. Select `Copy as path` option and the file path will be in clipboard. In terminal `Right Mouse Click` will paste the file path.

Comment: I am blessed with your honor all knowing one

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

CommercialArticles.txt is a file. You cannot go further inside a file to find more files/folders. So your path is incorrect.

After you fix it, you should also use "\\" instead of "/" while specifying the path.